# ClosedXML read styles when column and row is overlapping

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I want read the styles of this worksheet from Excel via ClosedXML. So on column "E" there is a Fill -> BackgroundColor (blue) and on row "15" there is a Fill -> BackgroundColor (purple). How can I read via ClosedXML which property is now the overlapping one (or which property was set last) so I can set the styles for "E15" correctly?

[image]

I was looking for some kind of attribute which indicates that the row "15" was set last and is now the "top layer" but I had no luck so far.

Has someone experienced a similar problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string fileName = "d:\\test.xlsx";  
  
using FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(fileName);  
using XLWorkbook workbook = new XLWorkbook(fs);  
IXLWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Worksheet("Test");  
IXLCell cell = worksheet.Cell(5, "E");  
Console.WriteLine($"5E value:{cell.Value} color:{cell.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor}");  
  
cell = worksheet.Cell(6, "E");  
Console.WriteLine($"6E value:{cell.Value} color:{cell.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor}");
```

Poperty BackgroundColor contains actual color
[screenshot of my test excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPHi0.jpg)

Also you can try to get all styles of worksheet.
((ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorksheet)worksheet).Styles
But XLWorksheet internal class and you get access to it only using reflection and this is not good practice.

Comment: Thank you this was it. I didn´t see it in the first place, because I was filtering only for the cells that has a "user-changed" attribute when reading the excel 
-> List<IXLCell> cells = worksheet.Cells().ToList();

But now I know. Thanks again.